# wxMaxima: Finding the closest larger/smaller number

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

How can one find the closest larger and closest smaller number from a maxima list? Which maxima functions should I explore?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe you mean `ceiling` and `floor`. Or maybe you mean `sort(mylist);` and then look at `mylist[k + 1]` and `mylist[k - 1]` for any element `k`.

Comment: e.g. ```list : [0, 0.014, 0.021, 0.028, 0.042, 0.056, 0.07, 0.084, 0.11, 0.17, 0.28, 0.42, 0.56];``` and ```x : 0.04;``` the closest smaller than '''x''' is 0.028 and closest larger is 0.056. Which function can let me automate this search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on finding the sublist of elements which are less than or greater than `x`, and returning the greatest or least such element. If there is no such element, `false` is returned.

```
(%i4) next_smaller (L, x) := 
         (sort(L), 
          sublist (%%, lambda ([y], y < x)),
          if %% # [] then last(%%)) $
(%i5) next_larger (L, x) := 
          (sort(L),
           sublist (%%, lambda ([y], y > x)), 
           if %% # [] then first(%%)) $
(%i6) list: [0, 0.014, 0.021, 0.028, 0.042, 0.056, 0.07, 0.084, 0.11, 0.17, 0.28, 0.42, 0.56] $
(%i7) next_smaller (list, 0.04);
(%o7)                                0.028
(%i8) next_larger (list, 0.04);
(%o8)                                0.042
(%i9) next_larger (list, 0.56);
(%o9)                                false
(%i10) next_smaller (list, 0.56);
(%o10)                               0.42
(%i11) next_smaller (list, 0);
(%o11)                               false
(%i12) next_larger (list, 0);
(%o12)                               0.014
(%i13) next_larger (list, -1);
(%o13)                                 0
(%i14) next_smaller (list, -1);
(%o14)                               false
(%i15) next_smaller (list, 1);
(%o15)                               0.56
(%i16) next_larger (list, 1);
(%o16)                               false
```

These functions probably could be made more efficient, but you might notice the difference only if you're working with long lists. Maybe see if this works before trying to optimize.